# How to insert different values from same row in multiple rows of a new table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the A table:

```
id bigint,
a integer,
b integer,
c integer,
date date
```

and I have to put every single value in a new table following by the date, in this way:

```
B table:
id bigint,
type integer,
date date
```

For example, if in my A table I had a row like this:

```
id a b c date
13 5 4 7 2014-11-09
```

I would like to put this values in B table like this:

```
id type date
1  5    2014-11-09,
2  4    2014-11-09,
3  7    2014-11-09
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpivot first the data using `UNION ALL` and then assign a new `id` using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id, col) AS id,
    type,
    date
FROM (
    SELECT id, 'a' AS col, a AS type, date FROM tableA UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 'b' AS col, b AS type, date FROM tableA UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 'c' AS col, c AS type, date FROM tableA
) t
```

If the new `id` is auto generated, you do not need the `ROW_NUMBER` at all.

```
SELECT a AS type, date FROM tableA UNION ALL
SELECT b AS type, date FROM tableA UNION ALL
SELECT c AS type, date FROM tableA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT  INTO A
    ( id ,
      a ,
      b ,
      c ,
      date )
VALUES  ( 13,
      5 ,
      4 ,
      7 ,
      2014-11-09
    )



ALTER TRIGGER NewTrigger ON A
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    DECLARE @id AS NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @type AS NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @date AS INT



    SELECT  @Date = INSERTED.Date
    FROM    INSERTED


    INSERT  INTO B
            ( Date,
              Type,
              id
            )
    VALUES  ( @Date,
              4,
              1 
            )

END
GO

SELECT  * A
SELECT  * FROM  B
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can try using REGEXP to simulate the sqame . Hope this helps.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEVEL,
  TRIM(regexp_substr(a.colk,'[^,]+', 1, level)) TYPE,
  SYSDATE
FROM
  (SELECT LEVEL,
    COL1
    ||','
    ||COL2
    ||','
    ||COL3 colk,
    SYSDATE
  FROM
    (SELECT 13 AS ID,5 COL1,4 AS COL2,7 AS COL3,sysdate AS dt FROM DUAL
    )
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(COL1
    ||','
    ||COL2
    ||','
    ||COL3,',')+1
  )a
  CONNECT BY regexp_substr(a.colk, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Contest for shortest code :) My variant is:

```
insert into b(type, date)
select unnest(array[a,b,c]), date from a;
```

Assuming that the `id` column in the `b` table is autoincremented.